Cosmological redshift to distance calculation: Why are imaginary numbers involved?
I was looking at this question and read through the linked article http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0007341v1.pdf. When I was attempting to compute the distance between two galaxies using the following formulae in the paper:
   
When plugging in $q_0 = \frac{1}{2}\Omega_M - \Omega_\Lambda = -0.55$ and arbitary values of $z_1, z_2, \alpha$, I keep running into the issue where $z'_2$ is a complex number! Have I performed an error in my calculations, or am I misinterpreting the value of $q_0$?

Did you read section 2.1 on $\Lambda \neq 0$?

It turns out that using the $\Lambda = 0$ formula for our universe does not work, as eshaya pointed out. Going to the section where $\Lambda \neq 0$, the paper presents this integral: $$\chi\left(z\right)=\int_{1}^{1+z}\left(\Omega_{m}x^{3}+\left(1-\Omega_{m}-\Omega_{\Lambda}\right)x^{2}+\Omega_{\Lambda}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx$$
Putting this into equation $(15)$, we cannot use the closed-form solution presented in the second line as that only works if $\Lambda = 0$. $P^2=\left(\frac{1}{1+z_{1}}q_{1}\right)^{2}\cdot2\left(\Sigma^{2}\left(\frac{\chi\left(z_{2}\right)+\chi\left(z_{1}\right)}{2}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)+\Sigma^{2}\left(\frac{\chi\left(z_{2}\right)-\chi\left(z_{1}\right)}{2}\right)\cos^{2}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$
Then $z_2^{\prime}=\frac{2P^2}{\left(q_{1}-2P^2\right)^{2}}\left(1+q_{1}-2P^2+\sqrt{\frac{q_{1}^{2}}{P^2}+1-2q_{1}}\right)$.
A key issue I noticed with this formula is the provided equation for $q_1 = q_0 \frac{1+z_1}{1+2q_0z_1}$, which has a vertical asymptote at $ z_1 = -\frac{1}{2q_0}$. As a result, I substituted equation $(27)$ from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.12097, where $q_1\left(z\right)=-1+\frac{3\Omega_{m}\left(1+z_1\right)^{3}}{2\left(\Omega_{m}\left(1+z_1\right)^{3}+\left(1-\Omega_{m}\right)\right)}$ (assuming that $\nu = \tilde{\xi_1} = 0$, which is a reasonable approximation).
This resolves the imaginary number problem and seems to be a proper solution to the question. Please let me know if I have made any errors in my calculations.
